# Как отменить действие метода setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint) на дочерние окна в PyQt6?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qlineedit, qdialog

Задача состояла в том, чтобы сделать главное окно программы всегда поверх остальных. 
Метод, который указан в заголовке сработал отлично. Но дело в том, что теперь все дочерние окна тоже отображаются поверх остальных и это становится очень неудобно. 
Например есть кнопка, по которой открывается окно со строкой `QLineEdit`, в которую копируется путь, который выбирается в проводнике. Это маленькое окошко при открытии проводника остается поверх него. Это окно я делал с помощью `QDialog`.

Попытался решить проблему использованием того же метода с другими `WindowType`, только применяя его к самому `dialog`, но это не помогло.
Вот фрагмент кода главного окна:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central = QWidget()
        self.central.setObjectName('centralWidget')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

    def show_path_select_dialog(self, id_, name) -> None:
        """
        Метод создающий диалоговое окно для выбора пути к модулю.
        :param id_: Идентификатор модуля
        :param name: Название модуля
        :return: None
        """
        def check_data(id_m=id_, name_m=name, path=None):
            # валидация данных после нажатия на кнопку "Подтвердить"
            if path and path != '':
                add_path_to_local_storage(id_m, name_m, path)
            else:
                select_dialog.info_label.setVisible(True)
            select_dialog.close()

        select_dialog = QDialog(self)

        select_dialog.setWindowTitle('Укажите расположение модуля')
        select_dialog.setFixedSize(360, 130)
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout(select_dialog)

        path_label = QLabel('Путь')
        v_layout.addWidget(path_label)

        path_line = QLineEdit()
        path_line.setObjectName('modulesLine')
        path_line.setReadOnly(True)
        v_layout.addWidget(path_line)

        select_dialog.info_label = QLabel('Путь не указан!')
        select_dialog.info_label.setVisible(False)
        select_dialog.info_label.setObjectName('infoLabel')
        v_layout.addWidget(select_dialog.info_label)
        v_layout.addStretch(1)

        h_box = QHBoxLayout()
        v_layout.addLayout(h_box)

        button_accept = QPushButton('Подтвердить')
        button_accept.clicked.connect(lambda: check_data(id_m=id_, name_m=name, path=path_line.text()))
        h_box.addWidget(button_accept)

        button_set_path = QPushButton('Указать путь')
        h_box.addWidget(button_set_path)
        button_set_path.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_path(path_line, name))

        button_cancel = QPushButton('Отмена')
        button_cancel.clicked.connect(select_dialog.close)
        h_box.addWidget(button_cancel)

        select_dialog.exec()
   
    def set_path(self, line_edit, name: str) -> None:
        """
        Метод, устанавливающий путь к модулю, выбранный пользователем в проводнике.
        :param name: Имя модуля.
        :param line_edit: Строка, в которую будет записываться выбранный путь.
        :return: None
        """
        dir_ = str(Path.home())
        input_ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, f'Укажите путь к модулю "{name}"', dir_)
        line_edit.setText(input_[0])
        line_edit.setToolTip(input_[0])
```

Дополнение:

1. Вот так у меня сейчас:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окно где находится строка с выбором пути перекрывает проводник. А мне нужно чтобы проводник в данном случае открывался поверх всех окон, в том числе поверх главного

2. Моя цель:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать. Как-то покажите то, что вы получаете и оно вас не устраивает и какие действия необходимо выполнить, чтобы получить то, что вы покажите. Также попробуйте показать то, что вы хотели бы получить, чтобы оно вам понравилось.

Comment: @S.Nick, вероятно, я и правда не очень понятно расписал проблему. Скажите, можно ли сбросить примененные флаги у окна? `WindowStaysOnTopHint` я применил на главное, а оно работает на все открытые дочерние

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.
2. Я не уверен что правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать и насколько правильная ваша задумка.
3. Я добавил некоторые вещи, чтобы запустить ваш код.

---

> [**QDialog Class**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdialog.html#details)
>
> Диалоговое окно — это окно верхнего уровня, которое чаще всего используется для краткосрочных задач и краткого общения с пользователем. QDialogs могут быть **модальными** или **немодальными**.
> ...
>
> Используйте перегрузку функции QWidget::**setParent()**, чтобы изменить владельца виджета `QDialog`. Эта функция позволяет вам явно устанавливать флаги окна переродившегося виджета; использование перегруженной функции очистит флаги окна, определяющие свойства оконной системы для виджета (в частности, будет сброшен флаг `Qt::Dialog`). 
> ...
> Примечание. Родительские отношения диалогового окна не подразумевают, что диалоговое окно всегда будет располагаться поверх родительского окна. Чтобы диалог всегда находился сверху, сделайте его **модальным**. Это также относится и к дочерним окнам самого диалога. Чтобы гарантировать, что дочерние окна диалогового окна остаются поверх диалогового окна, также сделайте дочерние окна модальными.
> ... 
> ... 
> [**Немодальные диалоги**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdialog.html#modeless-dialogs)
>
> Немодальный диалог — это диалог, который работает независимо от других окон того же приложения. Диалоги поиска и замены в текстовых процессорах часто немодальны, что позволяет пользователю взаимодействовать как с главным окном приложения, так и с диалогом.
>
> **Немодальные диалоги отображаются с помощью show()**, который немедленно возвращает управление вызывающему объекту.
> ...

---

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')                                   # +
        self.central = QWidget()
        self.central.setObjectName('centralWidget')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.show_path_select_dialog)               # +

    def show_path_select_dialog(self, id_=42, name='Название модуля') -> None:
        """ Метод создающий диалоговое окно для выбора пути к модулю.
        :param id_:  Идентификатор модуля
        :param name: Название модуля
        :return:     None
        """
        def check_data(id_m=id_, name_m=name, path=None):
            # валидация данных после нажатия на кнопку "Подтвердить"
            if path and path != '':
                add_path_to_local_storage(id_m, name_m, path)
            else:
                select_dialog.info_label.setVisible(True)
            select_dialog.close()

# -       select_dialog = QDialog(self)
# !!! или так :
        select_dialog = QDialog()
# !!! или так :
#        select_dialog = QDialog(self)
#        select_dialog.setParent(None)

        select_dialog.setWindowTitle('Укажите расположение модуля')
        select_dialog.setFixedSize(360, 130)
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout(select_dialog)

        path_label = QLabel('Путь')
        v_layout.addWidget(path_label)

        path_line = QLineEdit()
        path_line.setObjectName('modulesLine')
        path_line.setReadOnly(True)
        v_layout.addWidget(path_line)

        select_dialog.info_label = QLabel('Путь не указан!')
        select_dialog.info_label.setVisible(False)
        select_dialog.info_label.setObjectName('infoLabel')
        v_layout.addWidget(select_dialog.info_label)
        v_layout.addStretch(1)

        h_box = QHBoxLayout()
        v_layout.addLayout(h_box)

        button_accept = QPushButton('Подтвердить')
        button_accept.clicked.connect(lambda: check_data(id_m=id_, name_m=name, path=path_line.text()))
        h_box.addWidget(button_accept)

        button_set_path = QPushButton('Указать путь')
        h_box.addWidget(button_set_path)
        button_set_path.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_path(path_line, name))

        button_cancel = QPushButton('Отмена')
        button_cancel.clicked.connect(select_dialog.close)
        h_box.addWidget(button_cancel)

# !!! 
# -     select_dialog.exec()
# !!! +++             v^v^v
        select_dialog.show()                                  # !!! +++


    def set_path(self, line_edit, name: str) -> None:
        """
        Метод, устанавливающий путь к модулю, выбранный пользователем в проводнике.
        :param name: Имя модуля.
        :param line_edit: Строка, в которую будет записываться выбранный путь.
        :return: None
        """
        dir_ = str(Path.home())
        input_ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, f'Укажите путь к модулю "{name}"', dir_)
        line_edit.setText(input_[0])
        line_edit.setToolTip(input_[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(200, 400)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прошу прощения, я добавил скриншот к вопросу, так должно быть более понятно, что я хочу сделать

Comment: @Effex вот теперь мне точно не понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Внимательно прочитайте мой первый комментарий.

Comment: А теперь? Добавил изображение того, что мне нужно

Comment: Когда нажимается кнопка "указать путь" открывается проводник, но он открывается за этим диалоговым окном. И на важно, модальное оно или нет. Если убрать флаг, про который я упоминаю в вопросе, все работает как нужно. Но тогда задумка главного окна не осуществляется

Comment: @Effex   нажимается кнопка "указать путь" открывается проводник - это модальное окно и оно всегда сверху. И это именно так как вы показали на изображении `2. Моя цель` Вы пробовали запустить МОЙ ПРИМЕР? Что в нем не так?

Comment: Все верно, но если не указывается родитель, диалоговое окно не центрируется относительно главного

Comment: @Effex вы все прочитали о QDialog Class по ссылке, которую я вам предоставил?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, и еще раз извините за то, что отнял много времени